# How to use createSpyObj properly

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test the getDatabase Version function will pass the query as in to the executeQuery function in the getQueryResult() called by getDatabase.
The code is as follows:

`

```
var RequestHandler = function () {
  this.getQueryResult = function (sQuery) {
    this.checkConnection();
    try {
        return this.conn.executeQuery.apply(this.conn, arguments);
      } catch (err) {
        this.conn.close();
        this.conn = null;
        throw "unexpected error, please check application trace files for more information";
      }
  };
  this.getDatabaseVersion = function() {
    var query = "select top 1 VERSION from M_DATABASE";
    return this.getQueryResult(query)[0].VERSION;
  };
}
```

`

The test case that I wrote:

`

```
var RHandler = $.import("sap.hana.graph.viewer.XS_Backend.js.lib", "RequestHandler").RequestHandler;

describe ("getDatabaseVersion Tests", function (){
    var rHandler = null;
    var getQueryResult = jasmine.createSpyObj('getQueryResult', ['conn', 'executeQuery', 'close']);
    var conn = jasmine.createSpyObj('conn', ['executeQuery', 'close']);

    beforeEach(function() {
        rHandler = new RHandler();
        rHandler.openConnection();
    });

    function getAllQueries() {
        return getQueryResult.conn.executeQuery.calls.allArgs().join(':::');
     }

    it('should return the databaseVersion and match the query sent to getQueryResult', function() {
        rHandler.getDatabaseVersion();
        expect(rHandler.getDatabaseVersion()).toEqual("2.00.030.00.1502184660");
        expect(getAllQueries()).toEqual(/select top 1 VERSION from M_DATABASE/i);
    });
});
```

`
But it doesn't work at all. I am approaching in a wrong way. Can anyone guide me or let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: are u doing integration or unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like that:

```js
var RHandler = $.import("sap.hana.graph.viewer.XS_Backend.js.lib", "RequestHandler").RequestHandler;

describe('RequestHandler', () => {
  let rHandler = null;
  let connection = null

  beforeEach(() => {
    connection = jasmine.createSpyObj('conn', ['executeQuery', 'close'])
    
    rHandler = new RHandler();
    rHandler.conn = connection;
  });

  describe('getQueryResult', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      spyOn(rHandler, 'checkConnection');
    });

    it('should check connection', () => {
      rHandler.getQueryResult();

      expect(rHandler.checkConnection).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should execute query', () => {
      connection.executeQuery.and.returnValue('foo');

      const actual = rHandler.getQueryResult('bar', 'baz');

      // toHaveBeenCalledWithContext
      // https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spy-matchers
      expect(connection.executeQuery).toHaveBeenCalledWithContext(connection, 'bar', 'baz');
      // or default toHaveBeenCalledWith
      expect(connection.executeQuery).toHaveBeenCalledWith('bar', 'baz');

      expect(actual).toBe('foo');
    });

    it('should throw error', () => {
      connection.executeQuery.and.throwError(new Error('some error message'));

      expect(() => {
        rHandler.getQueryResult('bar', 'baz');
      }).toThrow('unexpected error, please check application trace files for more information');
      expect(rHandler.conn).toBe(null);

    });
  });

  describe('getDatabaseVersion', () => {
    it('should return version', () => {
      spyOn(rHandler, 'getQueryResult').and.returnValue([{VERSION: '2.00.030.00.1502184660'}])

      const actual = rHandler.getDatabaseVersion();

      expect(rHandler.getQueryResult).toHaveBeenCalledWith('select top 1 VERSION from M_DATABASE')
      expect(actual).toBe('2.00.030.00.1502184660');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you i will try this out. I think I am trying unit testing as I am testing the function in server side like getDatabase version which are being called by a service.
This is my first time performing testing so I am not quite sure with these things.

Comment: Hi Alexey everything works except this one 
 
`        it('should execute query', function () {
            //connection.executeQuery.and.returnValue('foo');
            var actual = rHandler.getQueryResult('select top 1 VERSION from M_DATABASE');
            expect(connection.executeQuery).toHaveBeenCalledWith(connection, 'select top 1 VERSION from M_DATABASE');
            //expect(connection.executeQuery).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
            //expect(actual).toBe('foo');
          });`

Comment: Expected spy conn.executeQuery to have been called with [ { executeQuery : spy on conn.executeQuery, close : spy on conn.close }, 'select top 1 VERSION from M_DATABASE' ] but it was never called.

Comment: I still havent tried understanding it I just wanted to check if it works. Still havent understood  completed CreateSpyObj function. Thank you for the help.

Comment: why does connection.executeQuery doesn't get called even after there is a call before to rHandler.getQueryResult(), i fail to understand this

Comment: updated test code, please take a look, it works for me

Comment: `jasmine.createSpyObj` creates an anonymous object with methods that are already jasmine spies: `var someObj = jasmine.createSpyObj(['method1', 'method2'])`. You can do it another way using `jasmine.createSpy` for every method and then create a new anon object like: `var someObj = {method1: method1Spy, method2: method2Spy}` but the 2nd way needs more lines of code

Comment: the problem in your code is that connection is the context of function call `.apply(connection, args)`. Passing function context cannot be tested using `.toHaveBeenCalledWith ` method. That's why I wrote custom jasmine spy helper -> `toHaveBeenCalledWithContext `. However, you can inspect calls args and see instance without this module

Comment: Oh I see but the toHaveBennCalledWithContext function is not available. I will try it out. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, for using `toHaveBeenCalledWithContext ` you need to add `jasmine-spy-matchers` package and then include it somewhere in the code. Please check tests here: https://github.com/robtweed/qewd-microservice-router You will see that jasmine-spy-matchers included in spec/helpers/matchers.js

Comment: thank you very much as you suggested i checked out `connection.executeQuery.calls.allArgs();` and it returned `[ ]`

Comment: I created a gist, take a look https://gist.github.com/killmenot/80195066c155f6bbeedc46cc5b925745

Comment: Hey @Alexey Kucherenko thank you so much i wish i could give you more credit for helping me so much. (: